# 500 error on Prestashop 1.7.8.7 installed with OVH

Tags: prestashop, ovh

I have a 1.7.8.7 prestashop installed with OVH since one month. I have restore the database from the client interface of OVH, then an error 500 occur.
I restored old versions of the db but the same problem, even I have restored all of the website with old versions but the same error.
Anyone can help me ? [image]

j'ai modifié ('*PS_MODE_DEV*', true) dans config/defines.inc.php ;
alors j'ai reçu ça :
[image]

I activate the debug mode on the code so all work, from the file defines.inc.php
but when I close the debug mode this new error occur:
"""""""""""
Warning: Zend OPcache API is restricted by "restrict_api" configuration directive
"""""""""""""

Comment: Please share more details, like the full and exact error message **in text form**, along with your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: It is also not about development or programming. You are operating a website and likely have an issue with your hosting environment settings. It would be more appropriate for other stack websites like SuperUser.

Comment: See also [PrestaShop PHP compatibility chart](https://devdocs.prestashop-project.org/1.7/basics/installation/system-requirements/#php-compatibility-chart) and ensure your hosting is configured to use a compatible PHP version. Also PrestaShop 1.7.8.7 is late and missing important security fixes. I'd recommend to update at least to 1.7.8.10 or (latest 1.7.8.11 as of writing this comment)

Answer (score 0):

Your database connection not work, verify informations about database in app/config/parameters.php and verify your parameters are good